# Не допускается метод findViewById() во фрагменте

Tags: android

Итак, есть фрагмент:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.R;
import ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.util.PersonalData;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 23.05.17.
 */

public class FragmentBelowFillDayRate extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_below_fill_day_rate, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FragmentBelowFillDayRate fragment = new FragmentBelowFillDayRate();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Почему-то при попытке напечатать

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById()
```

студия не подсказывает метод `findViewById()` и выделяет его красным. В других классах вроде всё ок.

UPD. Добавил решение ниже, но приложение вылетает теперь:

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_below_fill_day_rate, container, false);
    String daily = "text";
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.daily_calories);
    textView.setText(daily);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: С какой ошибкой вылетает? Посмотрите в AndroidMonitor stacktrace с ошибкой и добавьте в вопрос. А вобще убедитесь, что ваш лейаут ```R.layout.fragment_below_fill_day_rate``` действительно имеет ```TextView``` с id ```R.id.daily_calories```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, действительно, перепутал фрагмент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_below_fill_day_rate, container, false);

    final TextView mTextView;
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    return view;
```

}

Comment: Спасибо! Именно так.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById()
```

Comment: пару букв бы добавили, тут они бесплатны)

Comment: @Юлия странно, но при добавлении Вашего кода приложение вылетает.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ - чем это поможет в решении?